# jsf composite - ajax behavior for iteration elements

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

(in this example we use primefaces components, but question is not related with Primefaces)

**Introduction:**

In order to have ajax support for composite component elements we just use element:

- *composite:clientBehavior*

Let's look at this situation:

```xhtml
<composite:interface>
    <composite:clientBehavior name="dateSelect" event="dateSelect" targets="id111 id222" /> 
</composite:interface>  

<composite:implementation>

    <p:calendar id="id111" value="#{csController.selectedDate}" mode="inline"
                mindate="#{csController.minDate(2013,9)}"
                maxdate="#{csController.maxDate(2013,9)}"/>

    <p:calendar id="id222" value="#{csController.selectedDate}" mode="inline"
                mindate="#{csController.minDate(2013,10)}"
                maxdate="#{csController.maxDate(2013,10)}"/>

</composite:implementation>
```

We we have two elements and ajax support for these two elements. This works as expected.
We could even change to this interface:

```xhtml
<composite:interface>
    <composite:clientBehavior name="dateSelect" event="dateSelect" targets="id111" />
    <composite:clientBehavior name="dateSelect" event="dateSelect" targets="id222" />   
</composite:interface>
```

and this still works fine.

**Problem:**

I would like to change implementation to show custom number of calendars, not exaclty two like shown above. So I tried this:

```xhtml
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="firstMonth" default="1"/>
    <composite:attribute name="lastMonth" default="12"/>

    <c:forEach var="i" begin="#{cc.attrs.firstMonth}" end="#{cc.attrs.lastMonth}">
        <composite:clientBehavior name="dateSelect" event="dateSelect" targets="#{cc.clientId}#{i}"/>
    </c:forEach>

</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

    <c:forEach var="i" begin="#{cc.attrs.firstMonth}" end="#{cc.attrs.lastMonth}">

            <p:calendar id="#{cc.clientId}#{i}" value="#{csController.selectedDate}" mode="inline"
                mindate="#{csController.minDate(2013,i)}"
                maxdate="#{csController.maxDate(2013,i)}"/>

    </c:forEach>
</composite:implementation>
```

This of course doesn't work.

**Question:**

How to get ajax support for all elements generated by c:forEach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to follow that procedure to add ajax functionality for your components. Just use `f:ajax` into your calendars. As `c:forEach` works before it, that's not a problem:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="val" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <c:forEach var="date" items="#{cc.attrs.val}">
        <p:calendar value="#{date}" mode="inline">
            <f:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{bean.printCurrentValues}" />
        </p:calendar>
    </c:forEach>

</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Being this the main page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composites">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <composite:comp val="#{bean.calendars}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I added this listener method to the bean to check current dates are really changing:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    public List<Date> calendars = Arrays.asList(new Date(), new Date());

    public List<Date> getCalendars() {
        return calendars;
    }

    /**
     * Just prints the updated values ;-)
     */
    public void printCurrentValues() {
        System.out.println("Current selected dates: " + calendars);
    }
}
```

For your specific case you only would need to add a list of `minDates` and other one of `maxDates` in order to bind them to your `calendar` properties. Alternatively, you could also create your own class which wraps them to have everything packed. That's your own choice.

---

**Solution above** will work for `dateSelect` event and a provided listener. What if we want to have different events with different listeners?

Just define them on the interface and allow-deny them with JSTL's `c:if`. Here you have the composite implementation for a single input that can launch a listener method, also a dynamic number of `p:calendar` components, which will notify a user-defined method. **By default none of them is launched.**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="dateSelect" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="click" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="dateSelectListener" method-signature="void f()" />
    <cc:attribute name="inputClickedListener" method-signature="void f()" />
    <cc:attribute name="val" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText>
        <c:if test="#{cc.attrs.click}">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{cc.attrs.inputClickedListener}" />
        </c:if>
    </h:inputText>
    <c:forEach var="date" items="#{cc.attrs.val}">
        <p:calendar value="#{date}" mode="inline">
            <c:if test="#{cc.attrs.dateSelect}">
                <f:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{cc.attrs.dateSelectListener}" />
            </c:if>
        </p:calendar>
    </c:forEach>
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

And here the main page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composites">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <composite:comp val="#{bean.calendars}" dateSelect="true"
            dateSelectListener="#{bean.printCurrentValues}" click="true"
            inputClickedListener="#{bean.inputClicked}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

---

*Tested with Mojarra JSF 2.1.25 & Tomcat 7.*

Comment: And if we want to add more attributes to the ajax, we have to edit the composite component, for example adding `onchange`(speaking on a general case not particularly calendar). the solution here is very specific I think, it would be nice to generate clientBehavior on the fly. I tired using the same example in the question, the main problem is if the implementation tags (ex. calendars) don't have a pre-evaluated ids it won't work !

Comment: @HatemAlimam, that's a good point. I'm gonna update my answer, I don't think is possible to add ajax behaviour on the fly on the way OP's suggest. However, what as already seems like a solution is to have a set of possible ajax behavioured events and define which of them to use and their listeners on the interface.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker, It looks like you are right and adding ajax behaviour on the fly in not possible atm. At least not possible when based on the input attributes. But your second solution looks just fine.  I will do that this way. Thank you.